# Append blob to FormData without being forced to add a filename

Tags: javascript, php, blob, multipartform-data, form-data

I would like to figure out a way to append blob to FormData without being forced to add an implicit filename.

`formData.append('binary_data', blobObj)` always creates a default filename for the key `binary_data`.

I tried the following code, in order to avoid the implicit filename:

```
formData.append('binary_data', blobObj, null);
```

But it turned out to create the filename "null", as the request content shows:

```
...
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="binary_data"; filename="null"
...
```

Because of the existence of the filename, the PHP backend automatically saves the binary data as a temporary file, and adds the file information to the $_FILES array. I would like to figure out a way to post blob as FormData without being forced to add an implicit filename, so that the PHP backend can directly save the binary data in $_POST['binary_data'] instead of $_FILES['binary_data'].

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Could you override the Content-Disposition header when making the request?

Comment: @Evert I have no idea how.

Comment: Don’t add an actual BLOB then, but the text representation of it only?